# AWS: ELB becomes unreliable after removing public IP addresses from web servers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I have two **windows Serer 2016** web servers in the public subnets:

1. Each web server have their own public IP addresses.
2. Each web server has self-signed SSL certificate, has both HTTP and HTTPS bindings, and redirecting HTTP to HTTPS.
3. They are in a **Target Group**. There is an **Application Load Balancer** using that **Target Group**.

I could request the pages from the web servers directly or from the ELBs. Response is instant. All good.

Once I removed the public IP addresses from the web servers, the response from the ELB becomes very unreliable. It times out every now and then with error 504 Gateway Timeout. But sometimes it does work.

Why?

Comment: Your servers probably have dependencies in the Internet.  They should be on private subnets with a NAT  Gateway.

Comment: Thank you Michael your answer is absolutely the right answer. My web servers need to access AWS S3. Once I do as you said everything works. Do you want to post as answer?